# are redshift and Doppler effect identity with speed of light?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, redshift

we know that redshift and Doppler effect say wavelength and energy are relative to the speed of cause body, so how can I understand the special relativity which said that the speed of light is same regardless of the speed of body emitting light?

Comment: Speed is not the same thing as wavelength/energy, so why do you see a contradiction?

Answer (score 0):

1. redshift happens to a photon when it is coming towards us from a far away galaxy that is receding from us, in expanding space
2. as the photon travels in expanding space, its wavelength gets bigger, so it gets redshifted
3. the speed of the photons is c when measured locally, and it does not depend on the emitting body, you are right
4. when the photons are coming from a receding galaxy, in expanding space, their wavelength gets bigger, their frequency smaller, so they lose energy, you are right